# merge two arrays into one Laravel PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

hello I am working with collections and arrays in laravel and now I have the following problem: after grouping a data collection I have as a result something like this:

```
    [
          [
             {
                "id":1,
                "number":1,
                "name":"ACTIVO",
                "type":1
             },
             {
                "id":2,
                "number":101,
                "name":"ACTIVO CORRIENTE",
                "type":1
             },
          ],
          [
             {
                "id":7,
                "number":2,
                "name":"PASIVO",
                "type":2
             }
          ]
       ]
```

my question is how can I remove (or join) the inner arrays and be left with a single array as follows

```
    [
        {
            "id":1,
            "number":1,
            "name":"ACTIVO",
            "type":1
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "number":101,
            "name":"ACTIVO CORRIENTE",
            "type":1
        },
        {
            "id":7,
            "number":2,
            "name":"PASIVO",
            "type":2
        }
   ]
```

any idea how i could do this?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$yourArray = json_decode('[[{"id":1,"number":1,"name":"ACTIVO","type":1},{"id":2,"number":101,"name":"ACTIVO CORRIENTE","type":1}],[{"id":7,"number":2,"name":"PASIVO","type":2}]]', true);

$result = \array_merge(...$yourArray);
```

`...` - unpack all inner arrays, since [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) accepts variadic number of arguments. So basically, you're passing each inner array as a separate argument for array_merge. Read more about arrays unpacking [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Example with your JSON string: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3f81e329250f7d4974c38453d024c320096d3f4c

Comment: Fix this typo: Undefined function 'json_decde'. Must be `json_decode` instead.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo

Comment: If this is the answer, please close mega-duplicate questions instead of answering. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46861938/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Based on your dataset this should do the trick:

##### Solution 1:

[flatten()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten)

> The `flatten` method flattens a multi-dimensional collection into a
> single dimension:

```php
collect($data)->flatten(1)->all();
```

##### Solution 2:

[collapse()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-collapse)

> The `collapse` method collapses a collection of arrays into a single,
> flat collection:

```php
collect($data)->collapse()->all();
```